# Composer conflicting requirements

Tags: composer-php, version

I am trying to build a PHP framework for the company I work in, and the most crazy thing is ever happing!

I have one package that depends on other both in development yet.

Just to get started (they are in different folders, of course!):

I ran `composer init` to create a package xxxxxx/core-min, and the result was:

```
{
    "name": "xxxxxx/core-min",
    "description": "Dummy Minimal Core",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "New BSD License",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "My Name",
            "email": "me@xxxxxx.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {}
}
```

Created the Packagist Service on Github, Submitted, and everything is okay so far.

I ran `composer require xxxxxx/core-min` and got it perfectly installed.

Then, I ran `composer init` to create a package xxxxxx/core, and the result was:

```
{
    "name": "xxxxxx/core",
    "description": "Dummy Full Core",
    "type": "library",
    "require": {
        "xxxxxx/core-min": "dev-master"
    },
    "license": "New BSD License",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "My Name",
            "email": "me@xxxxxx.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

I ran `composer require xxxxxx/core-min` and got this message:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for zyneframework/core dev-master -> satisfiable by zyneframework/core[dev-master].
    - zyneframework/core dev-master requires zyneframework/core-min dev-master -> satisfiable by zyneframework/core-min[dev-master] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

This is tricking me out and I can't find any real solution!

Tried several GitHub issues and nothing!

Comment: Can't reproduce it. If I download just the `composer.json` from [here](https://github.com/zyneframework/core/blob/master/composer.json) and run `composer install` in that folder everything is running without errors.

Comment: Yes, I haven't tried that way. But it worked. I was wondering how to use "composer require xxxxxx/core" instead.

Comment: you don't need to require what is already in the `require` section of your `composer.json`. But even `composer require zyneframework/core-min` worked for me. I still can't reproduce it.